# Error deleting record in console ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, record

I am trying to delete a record using the console. I have a model for "User". I tried several methods in the console:

```
a = User.where(:id => '18')
a.destroy
a.delete

User.where(:id => '18').destroy
User.where(:id => '18').delete
```

Using all of these methods, I got the same error: "Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thx!

Comment: Raj's suggestion worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
a = User.find(18)
a.destroy
```

When we use `where`, result will be `ActiveRecord::Relation`, means multiple records, on which you can't call `destroy` directly. You will need to call `destroy` by iterating over the result.

```
users = User.where(:id => 18)

users.each do |user|
  user.destroy
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I can add something here, The issue with your code that you are passing string while it expects an integer 'Number'

Your code should be as the following:

```
a = User.where(:id => 18).first
a.destroy
```

Without using first array of object will be returned and you can't use destroy method directly on it, in case you don't want to add first then your code should be like:

```
a = User.where(:id => 18)
a.each do |obj|
  obj.destroy
end
```